# Проблема подключения библиотеки mediaQuery для intrenet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css

Добрый день.

Сайт сверстан адаптивно, с применением @mediaQuery. Проблема в том, что ie отображает на больших экранах такой формат, какой был бы, если бы это был экран мобильного. Сжимаю-разворачиваю монитор - размеры объектов меняются, но по умолчанию почему-то делает экран "разрешения" экрана мобильного.

Подключаю в хедер:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

Не помогает.

Залезала в скачанный css-ник (boot.min.css), что самое забавное - там сверху идут описания для маленьких экранов, а снизу - для больших. Первая мысль была, что он перезаписывает свойства последним блоком, но нелогично.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать пример с воспроизведением вашей ошибки на jsfiddle.net, либо линк на сайт, так как без взгляда на какой-либо код трудно угадать, что у вас может не работать. Также напишите версию IE, в которой у вас это не работает.

**Обновление**

Попробуйте подключить этот скрипт, может, проблема в том, что IE не понимает HTML5.

```
<!—[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]—>
```

---

А ещё у вас Jquery 1.4 подключен, для бутстрапа 3 нужен минимум 1.9.1, об этом в консоли хрома пишет

Comment: http://inconsult.org/ вот сайт.
в ie 9

Comment: спасибо. пробовала, с ним тоже не хочет.
нашла в интернете статью о Respond , по возможности хотела бы попросить тех, кто работал с данным методом, объяснить, как это устанавливается.